# Access gameObject in main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

`get_gameObject can only be called from the main thread.`

Is the error I am getting which I've figured out is to do with the way event handlers are implemented in C#.

In my Start method I have

```
EventManager.Instance.AddListener(EVENT_TYPE.UPDATE, this);
```

Then in my OnEvent handler method I have

```
public void OnEvent(EVENT_TYPE Event_Type, Component Sender, object Param=null)
{
    //Detect event type
    switch (Event_Type)
    {
        case EVENT_TYPE.UPDATE:
           Debug.Log(" UPDATE Timer event received Param = "+ Param);
            foo(Param as string);
            break;
    }
}
```

And then my foo method

```
private void foo(string param)
{
    Debug.Log("ASSERT foo gameObject" + gameObject);
```

So `gameObject` is null because the `foo` method is not on the main thread. So how DO I access `gameObject` then?

Comment: I recently implemented an eventing system in my own Unity3d project using delegates.  It allows you to run events in the context of where you want them to be fired.  I can explain how that works which I believe would solve your problem, but it'd be an alternate solution, rather than a direct answer.

Comment: What is `EventManager`?  That doesn't look like something built into Unity?

Comment: Why are you off-thread in the first place? As Dave suggests, you should perhaps explain what your `EventManager` is.

Comment: Thanks ChadF. I guess I should look into a delegate solution instead. The EventManager class I  am referencing from a recent book I purchased. I just googled and the actual class is viewable on google books as well. https://goo.gl/W3wgQZ

Comment: And just found one that uses delegates...will try this next!  http://goo.gl/FOzebW

Answer (score 0):

As in every Windows applications, in `Unity3D` you have to access the elements only from `Thread` they were created (main thread, or UI thread generally), and the error message clearly states that this is your case.

So you can solve this by two ways:

1. [Use `Loom` helper class](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/305882/how-do-i-invoke-functions-on-the-main-thread.html):

   ```
   Loom.QueueOnMainThread(() =>
   {
       Debug.Log("ASSERT foo gameObject" + gameObject);
   });
   ```

   or

   ```
   Loom.DispatchToMainThread(() =>
   {
       Debug.Log("ASSERT foo gameObject" + gameObject);
   });
   ```

   But in this case you have to [initialize the `Loom` object](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/662891/loom-initialise-per-app-per-scene-or-.html), for example, add some useless code in `Start` method:

   ```
   void Start()
   {
       var tmp = Loom.Current;
       // or
       Loom.Current.GetComponent<Loom>(); // irrelevant call to kickoff Loom.        
   }
   ```
2. [Use `Dispatcher` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx):

   ```
   Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
     DispatcherPriority.Normal,
     () => { // your work here });
   ```